# ANDROID Listview animation + onclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, swipe, onclicklistener

I'm using a custom `ListView` : listview in a layout (wich can be considered as my main layout) and a Cell object that use another XML layout.

At this point, no problem, each cell is visible and my `ListView` works fine.

But I wanna use a third party library (https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) to add a swipe gesture to my listview. And if I use this, my `onClickListner` callback on my cell can't works.

Both can't works together actually, only one, but I need the two of them.

Any idea ?

Comment: `Both can works together actually, only one, but I need the two of them.` Can you please explain what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to Swipe AND Click on my Cell. But I don't now why both can't work together.

If I include the swipe code, it doesn't works because clicklistener is implement. And if I comment clicklistern, swipe works.